# The Worker is refused to connect to client inside of NAT network

Tags: apache-spark

I set up a spark standalone cluster environment as below:

master: on cloud, has public IP address: master_ip_address
worker: on cloud, has public IP address
client: inside of NAT network

I run the following command in the client machine:
spark-shell --master spark://master_ip_address:7077

From the worker web UI, I check the stderr log, it shows:

```
17/10/17 00:54:39 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Started daemon with process name: 1060@jrWS2016-mSpark
17/10/17 00:54:39 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/10/17 00:54:40 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: dbadmin,jshen
17/10/17 00:54:40 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: dbadmin,jshen
17/10/17 00:54:40 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
17/10/17 00:54:40 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
17/10/17 00:54:40 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(dbadmin, jshen); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(dbadmin, jshen); groups with modify permissions: Set()
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1713)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.run(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:284)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:202)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$2.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$2.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:66)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /10.154.10.3:38572
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:232)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:182)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:190)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: /10.154.10.3:38572
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:257)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:291)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:631)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:566)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    ... 1 more
```

the IP address: **10.154.10.3** is inner IP Address of client machine, is not external one, so the worker cannot connect to client machine, that's the problem.

My question is: is there a way by setting some configurations or something else to make the environment works.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide more details? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Since your client is with NAT configuration no machine could connect from outside, If feasible would advise using Bridge network.

If that's not an option look for host-only adapter or at least one VM which has both networks NAT and Bridge/host-only, Then forward specific port to work as tunnel